Difference between compensator of point process under real parameter an its MLE estimator
Suppose we have some point process $N=N_{\theta_0}$ on the real line, driven by a conditional intensity $\lambda_{\theta_0}$ dependent on some finite-dimensional parameter $\theta_0\in\Theta\subset\mathbb R^d$. Given an observation of this point process $N$ on $[0,T]$, we intend to estimate $\theta_0$ by its maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) $\hat\theta_T$, which is the solution to $$0=\int_0^T\frac{\dot\lambda_\theta(t)}{\lambda_\theta(t)}[\mathrm dN(t)-\lambda_\theta(t)\mathrm dt].$$
Details about such procedures can be found in The asymptotic behaviour of maximum likelihood estimators for stationary point processes by Ogata, 1978.
I'm interested in the compensator of point processes, i.e. $\Lambda_\theta(t)=\int_0^t\lambda_\theta(s)\ \mathrm ds$. In particular, I was wondering whether something can be said about the difference $\Lambda_{\hat\theta_T}(T)-\Lambda_{\theta_0}(T)$. Does this satisfy some limiting equation? Is anything known about this in the literature? E.g. is $T^{-1/2}(\Lambda_{\hat\theta_T}(T)-\Lambda_{\theta_0}(T))$ Gaussian, or does it satisfy some (functional) CLT?
It is known that  $\hat\theta_T\to\theta_0$ in probability as $T\to\infty$ (see e.g. Theorem 2 from the paper by Ogata; which, however, does not say anything about the speed of convergence). Under regularity conditions from the same paper, $\lambda_\theta$ is locally Lipschitz in $\theta$, so $\lambda_{\hat\theta_T}\to\lambda_{\theta_0}$. Then it should not be too difficult to say something about $T^{-1}(\Lambda_{\hat\theta_T}(T)-\Lambda_{\theta_0}(T))$, but I'm particularly interested in some nondegenerate limit for (something like)
$$T^{-1/2}(\Lambda_{\hat\theta_T}(T)-\Lambda_{\theta_0}(T)).$$
Any help or reference is much appreciated.

There is a CLT in a more general setting in the paper "Two-step estimation for inhomogeneous spatial point processes" by Waagepetersen and Guan (2005). Your $\theta$ is $\beta$ in the paper and your equation for $\hat\theta_T$ is what they call the Poisson likelihood score function defined by $u_{n, 1}(\beta)$ in their paper. Although, they consider a point process on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and also estimate another parameter at the same time they still have a CLT for both parameters.

@rezoons Thank you for your reply. This (asymptotic) CLT is just about the parameters, right? It is not about the conditional intensities, or about the compensators, right?

Yes, you're right. Although, I think that using the delta method we can turn the CLT for $\hat\theta_T$ into a CLT for $\Lambda_{\hat\theta_T}(T)$. If we consider the function $g(\theta)=\int_0^T \lambda_\theta(s)\mathrm{d}s$ then under the right assumption it should be derivable in $\theta_0$ and so we get the convergence of $T^{-1/2}(g(\hat\theta_T)-g(\theta_0))$ this way if I'm not mistaken.
